# Overriding the Blog username breadcrumb in the native Blog module

Tags: 7, theming

I want to disable the blog username in the breadcrumb which reads:
Home > Blogs > John's blog > Blog post

I have found the function in the core Blog module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_view().
 */
function blog_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node)) {
    // Breadcrumb navigation.  l() escapes title, so we should not escape !name.
    drupal_set_breadcrumb(array(l(t('Home'), NULL), l(t('Blogs'), 'blog'), l(t("!name's blog", array('!name' => format_username($node))), 'blog/' . $node->uid)));

  }
  return $node;
}
```

How should I best override this function in my theme?

Answer (score 2):

A node preprocess function in your template.php file would probably do the trick:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'blog' && $vars['view_mode'] == 'full') {
    $bc = function_to_get_breadcrumb();
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($bc);
  }
}
```

This should happen early on enough in the page build process for the changes to make their way through to page.tpl.php. You could also look at doing this in `hook_node_view()` in a custom module if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It is always advised one should [**never hack core**](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core), you could use [Custom breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module to do it.

> Allows administrators to set up parametrized breadcrumb trails for any node type. This allows CCK-style node types to have "Home > User Blog > 2005 > January" style breadcrumbs on the node view page itself, synchronizing cleanly with custom views or pathauto aliases. Breadcrumb visibility can be customized via a php snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Just edit the "modules\blog\blog.module" file, and look for the function where get the breadcrumbs array:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_view().
 */
function blog_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node)) {
    // Breadcrumb navigation.  l() escapes title, so we should not escape !name.
    drupal_set_breadcrumb(array(l(t('Home'), NULL), l(t('Blogs'), 'blog')));
  }
  return $node;
}
```